# SWT- Widget Disposed Exception for Text Eventhough Parent is Open and visible

Tags: java, swt

I have a SWT Text and for some purpose when I am checking for Text's visible and Enable status I am getting "SWTException: Widget is Disposed"

```
if(text1.isVisible() && text1.isEnabled(){
    //Some Operation
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? `Text1` has obviously been disposed. (BTW: Please regard the Java naming conventions...)

Comment: Sorry for Naming Conventions.. My Question is why I am getting that exception even though Text is Visible and it is saying disposed?

Comment: it is hard to say here without seeing your complete code.. Check for whether you are closing/disposing/hiding the parent panel where the text1 is present. Also check for text1.isDisposed() returns?